# Replace all characters between the 3rd occurrence of “-” and the ":" in each element of a vector

Tags: r, regex, substring, gsub

Here is what I am trying to do:

Given a string, I want to remove everything after the third occurrence of the '-' and the character — assuming there is a third occurrence, which there may not be.

This is my expected result :

```
Initial string  
yy-aa-bbb-cccc1:HYT    =>    yy-aa-bbb:HYT 
yy-aa-vvv-vv:ZTR       =>    yy-aa-vvv:ZTR 
yy-aa-ddd:YTLM         =>    yy-aa-ddd:YTLM
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

We match two instances of characters that are not a `-` followed by `-` (`[^-]+-`) followed by another set of characters that are not a `-`, capture it as a group i.e. inside the `()`, followed by a `-` and set of characters that are not a `:` (`[^:]+`) followed by the second capture group that starts with `:` (`(:.*)`) and replace it with the backreference of the capture groups

```
sub("(([^-]+-){2}[^-]+)-*[^:]+(:.*)", "\\1\\3", str1)
#[1] "yy-aa-bbb:HYT"  "yy-aa-vvv:ZTR"  "yy-aa-ddd:YTLM"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("yy-aa-bbb-cccc1:HYT", "yy-aa-vvv-vv:ZTR", "yy-aa-ddd:YTLM"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub('(.*-.*-.*)\\-.*(\\:.*)','\\1\\2',string)
#[1] "yy-aa-bbb:HYT"  "yy-aa-vvv:ZTR"  "yy-aa-ddd:YTLM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the the first two fields and everything afterwards to colon and replace that with the first two fields and colon.  Note that `\w` matches any word character and the `\` needs to be doubled inside `"..."` :

```
sub("(\\w+-\\w+)-.+:", "\\1:", xx)
## [1] "yy-aa-bbb:HYT" "yy-aa-vvv:ZTR" "yy-aa:YTLM"
```

**Note:** The input `xx` in reproducible form is:

```
xx <- c("yy-aa-bbb-cccc1:HYT", "yy-aa-vvv-vv:ZTR", "yy-aa-ddd:YTLM")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing a `stringi` solution in there.

```
library(stringi)

sub('_.*:' ,':', stri_replace_last_fixed(x, '-', '_'))
#[1] "yy-aa-bbb:HYT" "yy-aa-vvv:ZTR" "yy-aa:YTLM"
```